# How to implement the evolutionary polynomial regression with a multi-objective genetic algorithm (EPR-MOGA) in R?

Tags: r, evolutionary-algorithm

I am trying to implement the evolutionary polynomial regression with a multi-objective genetic algorithm (EPR-MOGA) using R. Given there is no available R package for this topic, I wonder what is a starting point? Thanks.

Below are some references that talk about the method.

https://iwaponline.com/jh/article/11/3-4/225/40/Advances-in-data-driven-analyses-and-modelling

https://iwaponline.com/jh/article/8/3/207/31275/A-symbolic-data-driven-technique-based-on

https://ojs.library.queensu.ca/index.php/wdsa-ccw/article/view/12093